# Bootstrap collapse not working on table rows - Currently have to click twice before it collapses child rows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use Bootstrap collapse feature on table rows. I have a JS fiddle to demo what is happening as its not working properly. Currently you have to click twice on the Group to collapse the child rows (but this only has to be done the first time).

http://jsfiddle.net/48swgomj/

In the below code I have data-target as #collapsegroup1 and this is the id of my child components so not sure where it is going wrong:

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsegroup1" class="accordion-toggle rowscss" style="background-color: #41A1AF !important; color: white"><!--!-->
                                    <td style="text-align: left;" class="datatablerowpadding">Group A</td><!--!-->
                                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="datatablerowpadding">9,250</td><!--!-->
                 

                                </tr><!--!-->
                                <tr class="rowscss" id="collapsegroup1"><!--!-->

                                    <td style="text-align: left;" class="datatablerowpadding">Apple</td><!--!-->
                                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="datatablerowpadding">6,000</td><!--!-->
                        
                        


                                </tr><!--!-->
                                <tr class="rowscss" id="collapsegroup1"><!--!-->

                                    <td style="text-align: left;" class="datatablerowpadding">Bannana</td><!--!-->
                                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="datatablerowpadding">3,250</td><!--!-->
                                  


                                </tr><!--!-->
```

If you click on 'Group A' - the first click doesn't register the collapse, but when you click again it collapses the child. How do I get it so it collapses when you click the first time? Cant see where I am going wrong here. Once it has been clicked the first time, it then works perfectly fine so seems to be just the initial click on the group row.

I figured out when I click on the group it adds the class 'show' but as it is already showing I think this is the reason why you have to click twice. How do I prevent this?

On default I want it to show, I need it to toggle when I click the group. Not add the class show when it is already showing

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/yk4bqjfx/

I had to add the 'Show' class to the child rows as a default and this worked.

Example:

```
 <tr class="rowscss show" id="collapsegroup1"><!--!-->

                                    <td style="text-align: left;" class="datatablerowpadding">Bannana</td><!--!-->
                                    <td style="text-align: right;" class="datatablerowpadding">3,250</td><!--!-->
                                  


                                </tr><!--!-->
```